# Shortcuts cuando la aplicacion en c# pierde el foco

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, windows

**(Se esta desarrollando en c#, visual studio )**

Hola lo que sucede es lo siguiente tengo un panel en **windowsForms**  y con un shortcut cualquiera digamos **(CTR+A)**, asignado un elemento de un **menuStrip**, el comando ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
private void ocultarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.WindowState==FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }
            else
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;  

            }
        }
```

Esto lo que hace en pocas palabras es que minimiza el panel.

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que al undir **el mismo comando** se vuelva a **maximizar** pero no lo hace porque el **foco** de la aplicacion ya no esta en la misma (ya sea el explorador, el windows, otra app, etc).

Supongo que deberia de registrar un **shortcut** en windows que tenga relacion con la accion que quiero realizar, pero la verdad ni tengo la mas minima idea de como hacer esto ò si exista algun otro metodo.

Comment: Como es que haces para ocultar un formulario con un shorcut?

Comment: como dije esa parte ya me funciona, la duda es despues de hacerlo "visible=false", ¿como puedo hacerlo visible si es el forms principal?.

porque si lo hago invisible el focus ya no esta sobre el programa del froms si no sobre lo otro que este haciendo (navegador, juego editor de texto, etc)

Comment: Sigo sin entender como haces invisible un formulario de un sistema desde otro lado que no sea el sistema. Podrias mostrar como haces eso?

Comment: El punto es ese amigo lo tengo invisible pero quiero hacerlo visible te dare un ejemplo: tengo un ventana de windows forms y coloco un menu contextual que tiene un shortcut (ctrl+A) en ese shotcut coloco this.visible=false; en ese momento ya esta invisible mi windows forms, mi duda es, ¿como lo hago visible si es el  el panel pricipal de la aplicacion?.

Comment: Ah pero estas hablando de un shorcut en un meno de tu aplicacion. no un shorcut de windows.. Son dos cosas muy diferentes.. de ahi mis dudas... No tengo ni idea siquiera si podes hacer eso.. interesante...

Comment: Aclara bien el escenario en la pregunta.. y aclara que el shorcur es dentro de un menu en tu aplicacion.

Comment: Trate de aclarar lo mejor que pude, espero sea suficiente para que entiendas bien mi pregunta.

Comment: Si estas fuera de foco la aplicación no le veo nada útil crear un shortcut en windows para mostrarla maximizada, para eso existe alt+ tab

Comment: Yo le veo utilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas sobre plataforma Windows puedes usar la función del  API de Windows **RegisterHotKey**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        //Declaramos nuestras API y Constantes Necesarias
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
        private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

        enum KeyModifier
        {
            None = 0,
            Alt = 1,
            Control = 2,
            Shift = 4,
            WinKey = 8
        }

        //Sobrescribimos nuestro procedimiento WndProc para darle unan nueva 
        funcionalidad y poder detectar el evento del teclado registrado.
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY) //Detectamos el evento
            {
                Visible =true; //Mostrar Formulario
            }
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int id = 0;   //dejar por defecto 
             //Registramos El evento asociado al iniciar el formulario
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, (int)KeyModifier.Control, Keys.A.GetHashCode());       // Registar Ctrl + A 

        }

        private void ExampleForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0);       // Anular Registro
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Hola podrias explicar lo que hace?, quisiera saber si esto debe colocarse en la aplicacion para que se ejecute cada vez o es un registron que se hace una sola vez, que hacen los metodos, que traen esas variables, etc, gracias.

Comment: Ahí agregue unos comentarios mas.